# Convert two columns to key-value pair JSON string in Presto

Tags: sql, presto

Given this:

```
XXX YYY ZZZ
--- --- ---
AAA PPP LLL
AAA QQQ MMM
AAA RRR NNN
```

How do I convert it to this?

```
XXX JSON
--- ----
AAA {"PPP": "LLL", "QQQ": "MMM", "RRR": "NNN"}
```

FYI, I do not have access to `row_to_json` function in the database. Attempts have included:

- concatenating them as string (pretty hard to do since need to "group by" `XXX`, though it might just be escaping me how to do it)
- pivoting the table THEN attempting to concatenating them as string (extremely hard and non-performant at ~100 million rows for the runtime I'm aiming for)

Comment: Have you any PK ont this table?

Comment: @Livius None. Actually, there are five columns in the table, but these three are all I technically need since I'll be discarding the two during the transform requested above.

Answer (score 4):

[`map_agg`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#map_agg) combined with `GROUP BY` is what you are looking for.

Example

```
presto:default> SELECT * FROM t;
 id  | key | value
-----+-----+-------
 AAA | QQQ | MMM
 AAA | PPP | LLL
(2 rows)

presto:default> SELECT id, CAST(map_agg(key, value) AS json) FROM t GROUP BY id;
 id  |           _col1
-----+---------------------------
 AAA | {"PPP":"LLL","QQQ":"MMM"}
(1 row)
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks! Do you happen to know how to go the opposite way? From `{"PPP":"LLL","QQQ":"MMM"}`  to the original table?

Answer (score -1):

I do not have prestodb to test but maybe this answer bring you light how to do this.
I also do not know if RECURSIVE CTE is there avaiable. Sometimes word **RECURSIVE** is not supported but recursion work. You must test this self. 
Tested on PostgreSQL http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/07576/4/0.

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        T.XXX, T.YYY, T.ZZZ,  '"' || T.YYY || '": "' || T.ZZZ || '"' AS JSON
    FROM
        T5 T

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        T.XXX, T.YYY, T.ZZZ, C.JSON || ', ' || '"' || T.YYY || '": "' || T.ZZZ || '"' AS JSON
    FROM
        T5 T
        INNER JOIN CTE C ON C.XXX=T.XXX AND C.YYY || '_' || C.ZZZ>T.YYY || '_' || T.ZZZ
)

SELECT 
    C.XXX,  '{' || MAX(C.JSON) || '}' AS JSON
FROM 
    CTE C
GROUP BY C.XXX
```

Comment: Let me try, my man. Hopefully at least this one is included. Got no control on our database functions, sadly.